# how can i get the content of between two special strings in shell

Tags: shell, sed, grep, tr

I have two special characters,i want get the content of between them in shell.

Don't use awk ,because my linux can't find awk.

Comment: What kind of special characters ? tr or sed might do the trick ;)

Comment: @Jean-Christophe Meillaud  character strings like "AB" to "DE".can you make in details about tr or sed..

Comment: Re: "my linux can't find awk": That sounds like a pretty serious problem that you should try to fix, rather than working around it.

Comment: @ruakh How can i fix it ..

Comment: @choujayyl: That depends what the problem is. I suggest you ask about that at [Super User](http://superuser.com/) (one of Stack Overflow's sister sites).

Comment: It helps everyone if you supply a couple of good examples of input and expected output.

Comment: "my linux can't find awk" - What other standard UNIX tools don't exist in your broken Linux distro and what other limitations does it have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $ sed -n '/WORD1/,/WORD2/p' /path/to/file 
 $ sed -n '/FOO/,/BAR/p' test.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "ABxxxDE" | sed -e 's/AB\(.*\)DE/\1/g'
```

Will print out:

```
xxx
```

Comment: That works nicely for your chosen data (so +1).  Suppose the input were `abcABxxxDEdef`.  Your command would yield `abcxxxdef`, but there's room to suppose that the desired output is just `xxx` still.  Granted, the question should give examples of input and output (and doesn't, yet), but I think that's a reasonable reading of the question (and not a difficult fix to your answer).

Comment: @Tim I said character strings is not short,it is subsection,so you call me to echo"xxxxx" ,do i input the long strings in echo..

Comment: @choujayyl If you're data is in a file, you could use 'cat' instead of 'echo'. I don't think you ever said your character strings were not short. Perhaps you need to edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "This is a #TEST%" | grep -o \#[a-zA-Z.0-9]*\%
```

will yield

```
#TEST%
```

You can also strip the special characters using sed..

```
echo "This is a #TEST%" | grep -o \#[a-zA-Z.0-9]*\% | sed 's/#//g' | sed 's/%//g'
```

to yield

```
TEST
```

Comment: How can i get Develper, A  NBKDHKLAS from the string  (1000) ----$ Develper, A  NBKDHKLAS "Checking in the code to test the mock service by Junit as..." 29-Aug-2014 03:59 AM.. " occurs twice in the string..